# Define function in order to be continuous at $(0,0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Define the following function at $(0,0,0)$ in order for it to be continuous at that point: $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x\sin x+y\sin y+z\sin z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

I tried using the paths: $y=m_1x$ and $z=m_2x$ and saw that the limit produces value 1 but I can't generalize my result. Any help?

Comment: What is the limit of the given function as we approach $(0,0,0)$?

Comment: Use f(0,0,0) = 1. Wanna know why? post what you've tried so far first.

Comment: @JimVerr This comment belongs into the question body, so others will easily find this information without having to scan the comments. You might also include some of your calculations to allow for a better hint for the generalisation to arbitrary paths.

Comment: @AlexR Done. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the approximation of $\sin w $ given by $\lim_{w \to 0} w / \sin w = 1$, obtainable for example with L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: So, can I claim that $sinx=x$ when $x\to0$ ? If so, then $x\sin x=x^2$ etc. therefore it is easy to prove that the value of the limit is equal to $1$.

Comment: @JimVerr In essence, yes. It's a bit sloppy to say $\sin x = x$ when $x / \sin x \to 1$, but you basically have the idea. Make the ratios arbitrarily close to $1$ for each variable and then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin x=x+O(x^3)\implies \frac{x\sin x+y\sin y+z\sin z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=1+\frac{O(x^4+y^4+z^4)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\to 1$$